# Are questions about configuring KDE On-topic on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, scope

Recently, I came across a post which went like:

> How can I configure KDE to look like this:-
>
> [image: Some image]

Although, the question was closed as Off-topic because the poster was on Manjaro, it strikes my mind that are questions about configuring any desktop environment On-Topic on Ask Ubuntu?

I would personally categorise them as too broad, since achieving something like this would require a lot of steps. I would prefer these questions to be limited to something specific such as "which theme is used in the given image and how can I download it" or post multiple questions to achieve specific requirements.

But how does the community guidelines look upon such questions?

Comment: I would think that someone asking the question for a supported release of Kubuntu would be on topic 

Comment: Which is why the comment section would be used to really narrow-down the requirements, I think ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure. Why not? What would be the basis for considering such questions off-topic? Questions about configuring any desktop environment on Ubuntu can be asked.

The question in question was rightly closed because the OP was running Manjaro. If they were running Ubuntu (including all official flavors), then there would be no scope issue with the question.

There is also nothing else wrong with the question; it clearly shows the desired result, so is sufficiently clear and focused.

Comment: Zanna, your answer satisfies me but can you please look at the edited part.

Comment: @someone okay - how's that? I think you can edit again to remove the response to cocomac's answer as it has been deleted

Comment: Can you do it? I am on mobile and the mobile editing interface is a little pain :/

Comment: @someone no rush, you can just do it when it's convenient for you

Comment: I just removed my answer because you answered it well, and I realized that I completely misread the question so my answer didn't make much sense.